# Help with understanding of the solution to the following ODEs.

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I am not particularly well-versed with ODEs, and the issue that I have encountered is rather a basic one, which I am hoping someone could help me understand (the intuition at least, as I am solving these using numerical solvers on Python; however, I still need to understand this properly in order to code it). I have the following system of ODEs:
\begin{align}
\dot{\psi}_{ yt}&=\beta-K_1'\psi_{y t}\label{eq: ODE1}\\
\dot{\psi}_{0 t}&=\alpha-K_0.\psi_{y t}-\frac{1}{2}\psi_{y t}'H_0\psi_{y t}\label{eq: ODE2}
\end{align}

where $(\psi_{0t},\psi_{yt})\in\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$, $(\alpha,\beta)\in\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$, and $(K_0,K_1)\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}\times\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $H_0\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, and where $t$ is the time subscript with terminal time $T$, and with the terminal boundaries $\psi_{y T}=0$ and $\psi_{0 T}=0$. Suppose, I first integrate the first line (i.e., $\dot{\psi}_{yt}$) and evaluate $\psi_{yt}$ at $t=0,\cdots,T$. Does solving the second line then entail just substituting the solutions of $\psi_{yt}$ evaluated for each $t$ and THEN integrating? (essentially integrating a constant?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first equation is a constant non-homogeneous linear $n$-dimensional system, which you can solve exactly if you can find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $K_1'$. Consider the homogeneous system
$$
\dot{\psi}_{ yt}=-K_1'\psi_{y t}.\;\;\;(1)
$$
Let $\Psi$ be a fundamental matrix solution of (1), that is an $n$ by $n$ matrix solution of (1) whose columns are $n$ linear independent solutions to (1). We also add the condition $\Psi(0)=I_n$, the identity matrix. The fundamental matrix solution $\Psi$ can be constructed with the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $k_1'$ or it can be written formally as
$$
\Psi=\exp\left(-K_1' t\right).\;\;(2)
$$
In the case where $K_1'$ is diagonalizable to a diagonal matrix $D=\mbox{diag}(d_{11},d_{22},d_{33},\dots,d_{nn})$:
$$
K_1'=S^{-1}DS,
$$
for an invertible matrix $S$, then the exponential in (2) is given by
$$
\exp\left(-K_1' t\right)=S^{-1} \exp(-Dt) S
$$
where  $\exp(Dt)$ is a diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $e^{d_{ii}t}$. Thus $\Psi$ can be computed by an eigenvalue/eigenvector computation.

Then the general solution to
$$
\dot{\psi}_{ yt}=\beta-K_1'\psi_{y t}\;\;\;
$$
is
$$
{\psi}_{ ytg}=\Psi\int_0^t\left(\Psi^{-1}\beta\right)dt+\Psi x_0,
$$
where $x_0$ is the initial condition of ${\psi}_{ yt}$ at $t=0$. In your case, $x_0=0$, so
$$
{\psi}_{ yt}=\Psi\int_0^t\left(\Psi^{-1}\beta\right)dt\;\;(3).
$$
Now, you have that second condition, ${\psi}_{ yT}$, which means
$$
\int_0^T\left(\Psi^{-1}\beta\right)dt=0.\;\;(4)
$$
This condition entirely depend on $K_1$. In other words, you cannot impose it. Given $T$ and $K_1$, the condition above is satisfied or not. There are no free constants to play with in the equation above. In fact, in the case where the matrix $K_1'$ is diagonalizable, the solution (3) can be written explicitly as
$$
{\psi}_{ yt}=S^{-1}D^{-1}\left(I_n-\exp\left(-Dt\right)\right)S\beta.
$$
Thus Condition (4) becomes
$$
\exp\left(DT\right)=I_n.\;\;(5)
$$
Condition (5) means in effect that the eigenvalues of $K_1'$ must all be purely imaginary and of the form
$$
\lambda_k=i \frac{n_k\pi}{T},\;\;k=1,2,3,\dots n,
$$
where $n_k$ are integers. In other words, their imaginary part must be an integer multiple of $\pi$ divided by $T$.

Then, like you say, solving the second line entails just substituting the solutions of $\psi_{yt}$ evaluated for each $t$ and then integrating. The function $\psi_{yt}$ is not a constant so it's not like integrating a constant but perhaps you meant that in the sense that the RHS does not depend on $\psi_{0t}$.